# Let's burninate [o-ou]!

Tags: discussion, tags

[o-ou](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/o-ou) hasn't helped us much, it's only got 9 questions and 0 followers. It has no tag wiki.

## Should we burninate [o-ou](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/o-ou)? Created: 2010-08-07 13:32:11

Answer (score 5):

I'd vote against it, although I don't feel strongly about the matter.

Sure, it's only got 9 questions. So it's not super popular, but that also means it's not doing that much harm. Nine is at least enough that it doesn't feel like a waste to me when I click on the link to see the tagged questions.

In fact, I think I've used that tag before to quickly find other questions about this subject. It's a bit harder to use search for this, as a search for "[o ou](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=o%20ou)" has various irrelevant results about [the diphthong [ou]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296222/silent-e-at-the-end-of-words/296231#296231) or [truncated words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/249811/why-is-ammunition-shortened-to-ammo-and-not-ammu/249897#249897).

I don't think small, rarely used tags like this are anywhere near as much trouble as vague, common tags like "usage" or "grammar."

Comment: I think you answered the question about colo[u]r. I believe the tag should be more generalized, i.e. [kingdom-states] to denote differences between these two, or even [different-dialects] to denote when trying to understand differences of words or expressions between dialects. [o-ou] is only a *very narrow* part of the hypothetical [different-dialects].

Comment: @Constant'sErik: If we had been using tags like that when I was writing that answer, I would have had to skip over various irrelevant posts about other dialect differences to find what I wanted. I don't see the problem with having a specific tag that applies to a smallish, but not tiny number of questions.

Comment: Then what about [er-re] (like cent(er|re)) or other such quirks?

Comment: @Constant'sErik: I wouldn't mind a tag for that either. I think tags that cover around ten or so questions are fine. Tags that cover three or four questions are not really useful since it's generally easier to just link between them in the posts or in the comments.

Comment: @Constant'sErik: we do have the tag "[transatlantic differences](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transatlantic-differences)" and it could be added to some of these questions. It doesn't fit on all of them though.